# Gradings and direct sums notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, representation-theory, direct-product

I'm studying gradings of rings (specifically polynomial rings) and keep coming across notation looking like this:

$$\bigoplus_{\rho\in\mathcal{I}} {D_{\rho}}\mathbb{Z}$$

in this situation ${D_{\rho}}$ is a divisor. My question is what does this summand actually mean. I see that it can be isomorphic to several coppies of the integers but what do the product mean in this situation.

another example is

$$\bigoplus_{\rho\in\mathcal{I}} {x_{\rho}}\mathbb{C},$$

where $x_{\rho}$ is a monomial, and I am similarly confused.

Comment: Do you have a link? Is the context algebraic varieties?

Comment: Yes, the examples I am looking at come from this paper: https://acdc.amherst.edu/view/octagon:44/CONTENT page 3

Comment: *I see that it can be isomorphic to several copies of the integers* - I think this is exactly what it means. We could write the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as $\bigoplus_{n \geq 0} \mathbb{Z} x^n$ for example: here the interpretation is that it is a direct sum of $\mathbb{N}$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, with each $\mathbb{Z}$ being labelled by a basis element $x^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

''another example is $\bigoplus_{\rho\in\mathcal{I}} {x_{\rho}}\mathbb{C}$''

Each element of $\bigoplus_{i\in I} \Bbb C x_i$ is a finite sum $\sum_{i\in I} c_ix_i$, where $c_i\in\Bbb C$.